# Normalizing addresses using PostgreSQL and PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geocoding, tiger

I am trying to geocode addresses in Hawaii using the PostGres/PostGIS with the [13.1. Tiger Geocoder](https://postgis.net/docs/Geocode.html). In Hawaii, many street addresses take the following format: ##-####. This is problematic with the geocoder, which is setting the street address as 0 when using the `geocode` function.

For example, I run the following block:

```
SELECT g.rating,
    pprint_addy(g.addy),
    ST_X(g.geomout)::numeric(8,5) AS lon,
    ST_Y(g.geomout)::numeric(8,5) AS lat,
    g.geomout FROM geocode(normalize_address('92-419 Makakilo Dr, Kapolei, HI 96707')) AS g
```

And the output is:
`0 Makakilo Dr, Makakilo, HI 96707`

Can anyone share a workaround so that the house address is accounted for in the geocoder?

Comment: I have a similar issue with addresses in Queens, New York. I think it an be resolved by adding a custom rule to the `tiger.pagc_rules` table, but the syntax is pretttty hard to comprehend.